# Using regex in jinja

Tags: python, regex, jinja2

I have a JSON string that goes like:

```
jsonstring = '{"key1": "comma,separated,things": "comma,separated,things", "key3": "semi;colon;separated;things"}'
```

and I wanted to use it in a jinja template like:

```
{{", ".join(re.findall(r'": "(.*?)"',jsonstring)).replace(";",",")}}
```

Obviously that didn't work.

The string comes directly from an sqlalchemy model and I'm not able to work on it from python. Is there a way to do this and avoid having to process it with javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, define a new function in Python:

```
def regex(jsonstring):
    return ", ".join(re.findall(r'": "(.*?)"',jsonstring)).replace(";",",")
```

Then, define it as a Jinja filter(do this in Python, must after define the function):

```
app.jinja_env.filters['regex'] = regex
```

Finally, use it in Jinja template:

```
{{ jsonstring|regex }}
```